# Is it possible to maintain a subfolder structure for apex files outside of the local dev IDE environment?

Tags: apex, vs-code, folder

I am aware that I can create subfolders in my `classes` folder under `force-app` folder in VS code.

However, once I deploy these classes to my org and if they are pulled by another dev, is there a way to retain this subfolder structure? I notice this structure disappears completely outside of my local dev environment.

For example I'd like to be able to do the following to keep a structure as follows.  Each number represents a folder level, thus 3A and 3B are at the same level:

[1] Force-App
[2] classes
[3A] mocks
[3B] tests

Comment: Hi, if you're wanting to achieve this then you should look at utilising source control rather than relying on an org based development model. This is expected behaviour if the other developer is simply retrieving the classes from the org as the folder structure you've created a concept in your local file system not in the deployed metadata.

Comment: Thanks, this makes complete sense

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce expects you to use source control. See [this idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfkdUAB/hierarchical-categorization-of-apex-classes-and-vf-pages), where they specifically recommend using VS Code. The idea itself is marked as Delivered, meaning have no plans to expose this level of support inside an org.

[image: Update from Salesforce: This can be done in Visual Studio Code]

Comment: Thanks, this make sense now that I think about it.  We can have our folders setup in the git repo and branch off from there.